# Doubt regarding the calculation of first Born approximation of Yukawa potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, integration, scattering-cross-section

The expression for the scattering amplitude upto first Born approximation for Yukawa potential is
$$f^{1}(\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k'})=\int_0^\infty r^2 dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^{\pi}\sin{\theta}\frac{e^{-\mu r}}{r} e^{i \mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}}.$$ Now there is this argument to calculate this that we set the spatial coordinate system such that $\mathbf{q}$ lies on the z axis. But my problem is that $\mathbf{q}$ is not any arbitrary vector. It is the change in momentum vector $\mathbf{q}=\mathbf{k'}-\mathbf{k}$ where $\mathbf{k}$ is the initial momentum vector and $\mathbf{k'}$ is the final momentum vector. $\mathbf{k}$ is fixed (we generally take it in the z direction) and $\mathbf{k'}$ can be along any direction with respect to the z axis. So for different $\mathbf{k'}$s there are different $\mathbf{q}$s along different directions. So how can we set the spatial coordinate system such that for all $\mathbf{q}$ is along the z axis?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $f^1$ is a function of *one variable*, **q**, not **k** and **k**'. So you orient it, **q**, along z, then.

Comment: So in my mind, this is how I set up the problem. I fix a spatial coordinate system and fix a direction for my initial momentum $\mathbf{k}$. Then the incoming particles scatter and they do along several possible values of $\mathbf{k'}$. Now I  can find $\mathbf{q}$ for any one such $\mathbf{k'}$. To find the integral I assume that one such $\mathbf{q}$, is oriented along the z axis (or for a given $\mathbf{q}$ we rotate the system such that it is along the z axis). But what about some other $\mathbf{q}$? Do we just keep rotating the spatial coordiante system as and when we need for a new q?

Comment: The direction of $\vec{q}$ would matter if the scattering potential was anisotropic.  But it's not: it's spherically symmetric.  When you compute the integral, you'll find that it's independent of any angles, only dependent on the magnitude of $\vec{q}$.  Just try different directions for $\vec{q}$ and see what happens.

Comment: You start from the wrong foot. **k** is a fixed parameter and you have just *one* variable, **q**. You should pick the orientation of your dummy integration variable **r**, its *z* axis, to be along **q**, and do the integral.

Comment: ... the integral will be a function of | **q** | and that's it.